# Empty array in response PHP/JSON

Tags: php, json, post

I'm coding a php server sending arrays response using JSON. Now i simply testing the php code but the result is empty:

```
{"routes":[]}
```

There is my code in PHP:

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') {

    $region = $_POST['region'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE region='$region'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $dbdata = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dbdata[] = $row;
    }

    $obj = (object)[

        'routes' => $dbdata
    ];

    echo json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
?>
```

I'am testing in postman, sending POST:

```
http://MY PATH/filter.php?"region"=West
```

Comment: Why do you have quotes round `?"region"=West`

Comment: Its my mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to the top of the script. If there is anything funny it will show the errors.

2) Change the post to a get for testing purposes
3) Go to the page

```
 http://MY PATH/filter.php?"region"=West //-> remove the quotes
 http://MY PATH/filter.php?region=West //->This is what the request will look like
```

4) Do we see anything and what?
5) If there is nothing use variables to test things

```
 ex: 
     $region = $_GET['region'];

echo $region; //Should print West

$sql = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE region='$region'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results) // and so on until you see something you can use
$dbdata = array();
```

Comment: As a suggestion i would never use `$_POST["variable"]` as it expects that the value will actually be submitted - which coming from the front end may not be true. If it isnt set an error will trigger which may prevent the form from completing. Instead, i would simple test for `if(empty($_POST["region"])){` instead of the generic if posted. this works if it is the only character that you are concerned about if not i would use `$region = isset($_POST["region"]) ? $_POST["region"] : '' `

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a bug in

$region = $_POST['region'];
I changed to:

$region = $_GET['region'];
and I removed the quotes and I see the result.

Comment: @Hubu999 Your welcome!  set region to this `$region = isset($_POST["region"]) ? $_POST["region"] : '';`. If the $_GET variable is not set `!isset()` it will cause an error. Using the above will check or this and then if it is not set it will set it to an empty string

Comment: remember that POST requests are not represented in the URL that is GET

Comment: @Hubu999 your SQL should be paramterized look at php PDO

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 lines to the final result and see the result:

```
'routes' => $dbdata,
'valid' => $result != false,
'num_rows' => $result->num_rows,
```